# Cannot load libxml_ruby.so for libxml-ruby gem

Tags: ruby, xml, rubygems, libxml-ruby

I installed the libxml-ruby gem, with the `--platform=x86_64` flag, and whenever I try to `require 'xml'` I get an error.

```
Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require':
126: The specified module could not be found.
```

`- I:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/libxml-ruby-3.0.0/lib/libxml_ruby.so (LoadError)`

I checked, and libxml_ruby.so is in that directory. Any ideas on how to fix this?

I am using Ruby version 2.4.1 on Windows 10.

Comment: did you end up finding a solution to this?